# Can white dwarfs have accretion discs too?

Tags: white-dwarf, accretion-discs, accretion

Neutron stars and black holes can have discs of accreted matter for they have an extremely high gravitational pull. While white dwarfs don't have such high gravity theirs is of course also extremely strong. Can an accretion disc form around a white dwarf too?

Comment: What do you mean by, "theirs is of course too extremely strong?"

Comment: Their high gravitational pull, what else?

Comment: Use of the word "too" I think is problematic, it implies a comparison. I think "also" might be a better word than too.

Comment: Sorry, hope it's better English now. Thank you for coming up with my weird English.

Comment: Did you try googling for "white dwarf accretion disk"? That would get you plenty of information about accretion disks around white dwarfs.

Comment: I did try googling something but there were no recommendations. Regardless, you answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. They are called cataclysmic variables.